# KMP Algorithm Example

Tags: algorithms, strings

I'm studying KMP algorithm and I'm stuck on an example.

Suppose my text is "I am queen." and my pattern is "q".

The sp table will have only **one** value, **q** and it's **sp index** will be **0**. Mismatch will occur at the very first index.

According to the formula: **i - ( sp<sub>i-1</sub> + 1)** ; the right shift will be **0**.

And so the algorithm will get stuck and move nowhere.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for shifting is **i - sp<sub>i</sub> + 1** if you start indexing from 0 and **i - sp<sub>i</sub>** if you start indexing from 1.